# mini scatter matrix using subplots as a loop

Tags: python-3.x, seaborn

I have a dataset with 25 columns and wanted to examine scatter plots. I first looked at it with
Seaborn `scatterplot()` but this is too messy and there are too many charts to make sense of it all.
So instead I wanted to iterate a single column over all of the columns.
I created this simple loop:

```
for col in ds_num.columns:
    plt.figure()
    sns.scatterplot(x='initial_term',y=col,hue='logo_renewal',data=ds_num)
    plt.show()
```

This worked but it gave it in a one column shape. I'd like it to plot for a few in each row so I tried this instead:

```
for idx, col in enumerate(ds_num.columns):
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20,16))
    ax[idx+1] = fig.add_subplot(5,5,idx+1)
    sns.scatterplot(x='initial_term',y=col,hue='logo_renewal',data=ds_num,ax=ax[idx])
    plt.show()
```

But now I got  TypeError: 'AxesSubplot' object does not support item assignment

Any suggestions? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer with the help of subplots:

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(5,5,figsize=(20,20))
cols = ds_num.columns
for ax, col in zip(axs.flatten(),cols):
    sns.scatterplot(x='initial_term',y=col,hue='logo_renewal',data=ds_num,ax=ax,legend=False)
    plt.tight_layout()
```

Notice I removed the legend as it took too much space, this is of course not mandatory